# Angular 2 - Can't set form array value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder, angular-reactive-forms

I get this error:

> There are no form controls registered with this array yet. If you're using ngModel, you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout).

When using this code:

```
public settingsForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  collaborators: this.fb.array([]),
  rsvp: this.fb.group({
    latestDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
    latestTime: ['', [Validators.required]],
    guestLimit: ['', [Validators.required]],
    isRSVPOpen: false,
    isGuestPlusOne: false,
    isAutoApproveToGuestlist: false,
    isOnlyFacebookRSVP: false,
    isBirthdayAndPhoneRequired: false
  }),
  tickets: this.fb.group({
    info: this.fb.group({
      closingDate: '',
      closingTime: ''
    }),
    types: this.fb.array([])
  })
});
```

Inside `ngOnInit`:

```
this.eventSubscription = this.af.database.object('/events/' + this.eventId)
  .filter(event => event['$value'] !== null)
  .subscribe((event: IEvent) => {

    const settings: ISettings = event.settings;
    const collaborators: ICollaborator[] = settings.collaborators;
    const rsvp: IRSVP = settings.rsvp;
    const tickets: ITickets = settings.tickets;

    this.settingsForm.setValue({
      collaborators: collaborators || [],
      rsvp: rsvp,
      tickets: {
        info: tickets.info,
        types: tickets.types || []
      }
    });
  }
);
```

When `collaborators` contains a value, i.e it's not `undefined`, `null` or empty `[]`, something like:

```
[
  {
    email: 'foo@bar.com',
    role: 1
  },
  {
    email: 'baz@bar.com',
    role: 2
  }
]
```

Then the app crashes on the `setValue` line in the `eventSubscription`.

I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the form array with the control. That would resolve the issue. See [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html) guide if you need to know how to do that. If you are using `ngModel` it would probably worth to remove it.

Answer (score 7):

Before calling `setValue(data)` on a FormGroup or FormArray, the FormGroup or FormArray must have the **exactly** same structure of the `data`. Only the structure matters, the value in the FormGroup or FormArray will be replaced by `data`.

Example, if your data is

```
let data = [ {a: 1, b:2}, {a: 3, b: 4} ]
```

Then the FormArray must has 2 FormGroups and each FormGroup must has one FieldControl called `a` and one called `b`. You can do something like this:

```
let fa = this.formBuilder.array([
  this.formBuilder.group({a: 0, b:0}),
  this.formBuilder.group({a: 0, b:0})
])
fa.setValue(data)
```

If your data is of more complex structure, the FormArray needs to have the same complex structure.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build your form OnInit before setting its value. Try something like this :

```
settingsForm: FormGroup; 

buildForm(): void {
   settingsForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      //content of settingsForm
   })
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
    this.eventSubscription = this.af.database.object('/events/' + this.eventId)
    //...
    this.settingsForm.setValue({ //you can try .patchValue to set only available value
        //...
    })
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing right away. you don't have to do it in the on init hook.

Comment: ok, I had similar issue and this solved it. I thought it was the same issue :(. Did you check this [blog post](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value). Citation: "Providing your FormControl exists, Angular moves onto the Object.keys loop, however will first check that the control is missing for that value also via _throwIfControlMissing:"

Comment: Ye it was a problem with missing form group, so I had to loop over all the objects and then push a new group to the form array for each. Bit annoying and weird design choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will help

```
 import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

consutructor(public  fb:FormBuilder) { }

    public buildcollaboratorsGroup(fb:FormBuilder):FormGroup {
        return fb.group({
                            email:'',
                            role:''
                });
    }

ngOnInit() {
    public settingsForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    collaborators:this.fb.array([this.buildcollaboratorsGroup(this.fb)])
    });     

    this.setFormArrayValue();
 }


    // I am trying set only one value if it's multiple use foreach        
    public setFormArrayValue() {
        const controlArray = <FormArray> this.settingsForm.get('collaborators');
        controlArray.controls[0].get('email').setValue('yourEmailId@gmail.com');
        controlArray.controls[0].get('role').setValue(2);
    }

    // I am trying remove only one value if it's multiple use foreach        
    public removeFormArrayValue() {
        const controlArray = <FormArray> this.settingsForm.get('collaborators');
           controlArray.removeAt(0);        
    }
}
```