# Cannot set initial form values into FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I have a reactive form that on `cancel` has to set again the initial form values into the formGroup.

```
import { Map } from "immutable";

@Input() data: any;

public ngOnInit() {
    if (this.data && this.data.controls) {
        this.group = this.fb.group({
            isActive: [this.data.isActive],
            items: this.fb.array(this.buildFormArray(this.data.controlPerformers)),
            });

        // Deep copy of the formGroup with ImmutableJs
        this.originalFormData = Map(this.group).toJS();
    }
}

 public buildFormArray(controllers: IControlPerformer[]) {
    return controllers.map((ctlr) => {
        return this.fb.group({
            user: [ctrl.userData],
            ctrlName: [ctlr.name, Validators.required],
            date: [moment(ctlr.date).toDate(), Validators.required],
        });
    });
}

public cancel() {
  const existingItems = this.group.get("items") as FormArray;
  while (existingItems.length) {
            existingItems.removeAt(0);
        }

        // Here the error when trying to set the FormArray value
        this.group.setValue(this.originalFormData.value);  
   }
```

The error message:

> There are no form controls registered with this array yet. If you're using ngModel, you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786445/angular-2-cant-set-form-array-value) had the same issue, but I could not fix it in my case.

UPDATE - Below The value of `formGroup`. It looks good and properly initialized.

```
{
 "isActive": true,
 "items": [
  {
   "user": "Walter",
   "ctrlName": "Orders",
   "date": "2018-03-18T23:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you remove items from the form array, then you need to add them anew, since `setValue` or `patchValue` functions do not create form control if it is missing, but rather only set/modify existing form control value. So, just add new controls to empty `FormArray`:

```
public cancel() {
  const existingItems = this.group.get("items") as FormArray;
  while (existingItems.length) {
    existingItems.removeAt(0);
  }

  // Even adding a new FormGroup to the array, the exception remains.
  // existingItems.push(this.fb.group({})););

  // Here the error when trying to set the FormArray value
  this.group.patchValue(this.originalFormData.value);
  this.originalFormData.value.items.forEach(item => {
    existingItems.push(this.fb.group(item)); 
  });
}
```

STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsglab?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: I am facing a issue while push into formarray I need to set error if have for that form array control how could do that

Comment: you can set error on any AbstractControl with `setErrors()` method (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/593bd594e3419a2c834707e0f5d1dc86e1f94418/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L812), like `existingItems.setErrors({yourError: true})`. To get errors you can use `getError()` or examine `existingItems.errors` object

Comment: I have set error on value changes but while creating a form array initially from server response i can able to set value but not able to do that for errors could you please look on it yow will get better clarity what i am asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63888311/how-can-we-set-errors-on-form-array-control-dynamically-on-initally-page-load